# Scala reading file with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a file that look like this:

```
you 0.0432052044116
i 0.0391075831328
the 0.0328010698268
to 0.0237549924919
a 0.0209682886489
it 0.0198104294359
```

And I'd like to store it in a RDD (key,value) with (you,0.0432) for example.
For the moment I only did that algorithm

```
val filename = "freq2.txt"
try {
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
    val tuple = line.split(" ")
    val key = tuple(0)
    val words = tuple(1)
    println(s"${key}")
    println(s"${words}")
  }

} catch {
  case ex: FileNotFoundException => println("Couldn't find that file.")
  case ex: IOException => println("Had an IOException trying to read that file")
}
```

But I don't know how to store the data...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly read the data into an RDD:

```
val FIELD_SEP = " " //or whatever you have
val dataset = sparkContext.textFile(sourceFile).map(line => {
    val word::score::other = line.split(FIELD_SEP).toList
    (word, score)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val filename = "freq2.txt"
sc.textFile(filename).split("\\r?\\n").map(x =>{
                  var data = x.trim().split(" ")
                  (data(0), data(1))
          }).map(y => println(y));
```